# Rails select 'Other' option creating text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Given a standard select code:

```
<%= f.select :type_name, [['Genomics','Genomics'],['Proteomics','Proteomics'],['Transcriptomics','Transcriptomics'],['Other','Other'] %>
```

Can someone explain how I would go about creating a text field when 'Other' is selected? So that the type_name can be something other than the options in the select?

I realise this is a simple question, but I haven't found a concise answer as of yet!

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of ways to do this, but they all require JavaScript. The general approach I like is to put a hidden text field in the form, then attach a JavaScript event handler to the `select` tag that shows the field when the "Other" option is selected.

Here's a gist of the [script I typically use](https://gist.github.com/masonjm/1c221475fc099c90ba30) for this. It handles the JavaScript binding using data attributes. Add the script to your assets, then put something like this in your form:

```
<%= f.select :type_name, [['Genomics','Genomics'],['Proteomics','Proteomics'],['Transcriptomics','Transcriptomics'],['Other','Other'] %>
<%= f.text_field :type_name_other, "data-depends-on" => "#object_type_name", "data-depends-on-value" => "Other" %>
```

where `#object_type_name` is the HTML id of your dropdown.

Comment: So I believe I've figured out the Rails HTML ID, and I've got it so the textbox is hidden when I open the form. However, when I click other, it doesn't appear! The ID is just: `...['Other','Other']], {}, :id => "name_of_id"`, correct?

Comment: Can you post the generated html?

Comment: The page uses the nested_form gem and the dropbox in question starts on line [126](https://gist.github.com/lutrasdebtra/846e451ed20eb41ac8d4).

Comment: The HTML looks right, but I'm not familiar with the framework you're using. You'll need to find a way to bind the Javascript event handler after your template is rendered to HTML. Maybe it fires a custom event?

Comment: The gem in question is [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form), I noticed it has a section on Javascript Events, should I be looking at that?

Comment: Yep. It looks like nested:fieldAdded is what you want.

Comment: Or in addition too, yeah.

Comment: Ok cool, new problem! The server is spitting up: `Started GET "/javascripts/depends_on.js"` When my depends_on.js is in assets/javacripts/ any ideas?

Comment: That doesn't look familiar, no. Sorry :-)

Comment: Fixed that, still no luck changing to `$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded` I'm afraid! Ah well, I shall keep plugging away. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an attr_accessor on the model f is attached to (like type_name_other), add a text_field to the form below the select for type_name_other in a div that is initially hidden (in CSS: display:none), then create a javascript listener that detects when the select form has changed and if the selected ansser is "other" show the hidden field else hide it. You will then need to see if type_name_other has a value when processing the form and use it if so.